# Remotely debug iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, remote-debugging, testflight

I am developing an iOS (5.0+) app, which works very fine on 6 different devices in our company.
When we send the build to the customer, they report they have tested it on 5 different devices and the app is always crashing right after launch.
I have integrated TestFlight and Flurry SDKs to track usage and problems.

The strange thing is that no crashes are reported from both TestFlight and Flurry.

I have adviced the customer to remove the provisioning profiles and try to install everything from scratch, which did not produce different results.

The app is in the App Store, approved from the first try.

It is even stranger that the customer reports crashing when installing a TestFlight build and installing from the App Store.

Is the app going to be approved in the App Store if it crashes right after launch?

Any ideas on how to remotely debug the app or how to proceed in this case?

Thanks and happy holidays!

Comment: Could be a localisation issue? Presumably the App Store approvers checked in English.  Can you change one of your devices to the language in the other country and try testing again?

Comment: Very good guess - the app is in German. But, there is one issue, I couldn't change the default language in App Store to German. It is still English. I think the customer's devices are set to German and all of our company's are set to English. We will try to change the language now..

Comment: Yes, that's it the problem! Many thanks! When I set the iPhone to German, the app crashes even before the loading screen. Could you maybe suggest a way to resolve it?

Comment: Grab a logfile of the exception and post an extract here (updating your question); the problem could be almost anything (i.e. a xib issue, Localizable.strings issue). Hard to know without an error to look at.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard' in bundle NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/F5C5B1CD-18E4-4421-93CE-B8CA9A6FC5F8/XXXXXXXXXXXX.app> (loaded)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x390d32a3 0x32fc297f 0x32591d59 0x323d440b 0x3225d799 0x32205c39 0x322056cd 0x3220511b 0x373e85a3 0x373e81d3 0x390a8173 0x390a8117 0x390a6f99 0x39019ebd 0x39019d49 0x3225c47d 0x322592f9 0x3f2a5 0x3f240)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by adding both German and English localization to the project settings and having 2 storyboards for each language. Big up @RoboticCat!

Answer (score 3):

One option is to ensure your logging and get the crash logs.  This Apple documentation shows how to get the logs both with and without Xcode available:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1747/_index.html

After you get the logs, here's documentation on how to read and analyze:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Comment: The problem is that the customer is in another country and we do not have physical access to the devices they are using. I have adviced them to upload their crash reports using iTunes but still waiting for them.

Comment: Yes, that's the benefits of logs - they can send them to you even from another country :)